# How to set GIT_DIR in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I have a repository where the `.git` directory is not in the same location as the files being tracked. Because of this, when I open my project folder in VS Code I get no git support.

I cannot find a place to put the environment variables. In the terminal I would just do `export GIT_DIR=~/somedir/`. I tried this in the VSC terminal but is only recognized for the terminal itself, not for the editor area (for example, to show which code I have changed).

I also found in settings *Terminal > Integrated > Env : Linux* that allows adding the environment variable to a settings.json but this is only recognized by the integrated terminal.

How do I set, in VS Code, the environment variable `GIT_DIR` for my project to have git working properly?

Answer (score 1):

The [VSCode issue 77215](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77215) suggests [launching VSCode itself with the right variable set](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77215#issuecomment-1266033300):

```bash
alias dotfiles="GIT_WORK_TREE=~ GIT_DIR=$DOTFILES_DIR"
dotfiles git status
dotfiles code ~
```

Another approach would be to [use `git worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) (a different folder per branch, from a common cloned repository), but [it is not yet supported by VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68038#issuecomment-1114145216).